# Excel VBA sort method, run time error 1004, "The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it is whithin..."

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am trying to sort a range based on two different condiditons. 
In order to do so I recorded a macro that works perfectly.

When I tried to replace som of the macro-lines of code into 
my own variables etc, the code did not work and threw me several different error messages.

1. The first i got was: "Run time error 438. Object does not support this property or method"
2. The other error message a got was "Run time error 1004. The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."

Here is the code from the Macro-recorder (it works):

```
Sub CustomSort()
' CustomSort Macro
    Range("A1:H958").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Run Data from Notes").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Run Data from Notes").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A958"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Run Data from Notes").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H2:H958"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Run Data from Notes").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:H958")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I changed the code to (does not work and gives me "Run time Error 438"):

```
 Dim StatusRange As Range
    Dim PartNumber As Range
    Dim WholeRange As Range
    Dim wbkToRun As Workbook
    Dim NewData As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set wbkToRun = ThisWorkbook
    Set NewData = Worksheets("Run Data from Notes")
    LastRow = NewData.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set WholeRange = NewData.Range("A2:H" & LastRow)
    WholeRange.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.NewData.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wbkToRun.NewData.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=WholeRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    wbkToRun.NewData.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=WholeRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    With wbkToRun.NewData.Sort
        .SetRange WholeRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

When using the Macro-recorders code, but changing the range into my dynamically set range "WholeRange" it give me the error message: "Run time error 1004. The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank."

```
WholeRange.Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Run Data from Notes").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Run Data from Notes").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=WholeRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Run Data from Notes").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=WholeRange, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Run Data from Notes").Sort
        .SetRange WholeRange
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

It breaks on ".Apply"

Can someone please explain why my two codes above does not work? 
And what difference there is between my codes and the macro recorded code. 
Thanks.

Comment: `NewData` isn't a member of `ActiveWorkbook`.  Just use the reference *itself* instead of trying to call it from `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit and give an example? Did not fully understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many errors in the code.
First as said @Comintern, your range object `NewData` is an object variable per itself, it is not a `property` of its parent worksheet. Therefore `wbkToRun.NewData` and `ActiveWorkbook.NewData` are not valid VBA.

Second, when sorting, the `key` parameter cannot be a multi-column range. Each key should be either be a column, or a range that has only one column.

```
With NewData.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add key:=.Columns("A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add key:=.Columns("H"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange WholeRange
    .header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: This Code works. Thanks a lot! Just a ".Columns()" should be "Columns()" without the dot infront.